# needed any running example for ng-sidebar implementation

Tags: angular

I am new to angular2 i want to create sidebar using ng-sidebar ,
But the documentation they had given in readme.MD doc is quite confusing .I am not able to implement in my already build application.
If somebody have any implement experience in ng-sidebar please let me know how to call that component in my application?
I am very much confused about forRoot method.

Comment: What do you exactly mean by `ng-sidebar`? Which library's component are you talking about? Is it Material2's sidenav or something else?

Comment: i want to implement ng-sidebar here is the link : https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-sidebar

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Setup:

1. Run `npm install --save ng-sidebar`
2. In your `app.module.ts`, add following:

   ```
   import { SidebarModule } from 'ng-sidebar';
   ```

   Add `SidebarModule.forRoot()` inside `imports: []` in `@NgModule`, should look like something like below:

   ```
   @NgModule({
     declarations: [AppComponent],
     imports: [BrowserModule, SidebarModule.forRoot()],
     bootstrap: [AppComponent],
   })
   ```
3. In `app.component.html` add:

   ```
   <ng-sidebar-container>

     <ng-sidebar [(opened)]="_opened">
       <p>Sidebar contents</p>
     </ng-sidebar>

     <div ng-sidebar-content>
       <button (click)="_toggleSidebar()">Toggle sidebar</button>
     </div>

   </ng-sidebar-container>
   ```

   In `app.component.ts` add:

   ```
   private _opened: boolean = false;

   private _toggleSidebar() {
     this._opened = !this._opened;
   }
   ```

[Working demo](https://echeung.me/ng-sidebar/)

[Code of working demo/Example of calling `ng-sidebar` in component](https://github.com/arkon/ng-sidebar/blob/master/demo/src/demo/demo.component.ts)

Comment: getting error : attribute ng-sidebar-content is not allowed here less... (Ctrl+F1) 
This inspection highlights unknown HTML tag attributes as invalid, and lets mark such attributes as Custom to avoid highlighting them as invalid

Comment: Nehal Thanks, it worked for me know, But this demo is using style in scss so not able to implement is it imported as normal css or some special configuration needed?:-)

Comment: There's no special configuration needed. You can include a regular css style file for your component and use `>>>` or `/deep/` to change `ng-siebar` classes. In `ng-sidebar` doc's it say:


> Various class names are attached to the sidebar and container for easier styling. If you are using Angular's default emulated view encapsulation, you may have to use the `>>>`  selector to target the sidebar's classes.

Comment: In app.component.html --> all the sidenav contents are written. Is there a way to encapsulate it in a component

Answer (score 1):

For Angular6, if you are facing the issue that the sidebar is not appearing (silently failing without appearing),
**add a height** style element in the [code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44988029/9850713) provided by @Nehal like this:

```
<ng-sidebar-container style = "height: 100vh">
    <ng-sidebar [(opened)]="_opened" mode = "push" >
        <p> this is in sidebar</p>
    </ng-sidebar>
    <div ng-sidebar-content>
        <button (click)="_toggleSidebar()">Toggle sidebar</button>
    </div>
</ng-sidebar-container>
```

See my previous answer for the [Working Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45065156/ng-sidebar-angular-2-implementation-issue/52923156#52923156)

Comment: just follow up, how to load a dynamic components inside ng-sidebar-content tag based on different URL paths?