# ng-sidebar (Angular 2) implementation issue

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-directive

I need to make use of ng-sidebar to display a collapsible sidebar menu to the left on click on button in header.

app.component.html

```
<div class="page-header custom-phead">
    <ng-sidebar-container>
     <ng-sidebar [(opened)]="_opened">
        <p>Sidebar contents</p>
      </ng-sidebar>

<div ng-sidebar-content>
<button (click)="_toggleSidebar()">Toggle</button>
</div>
</ng-sidebar-container>
<form class="heading">
<input type="text" name="search" [(ngModel)]="search"><input type="image" [src]="'../resource/searchicon.png'">
</form>
</div>
```

And in app.component.ts ,

```
     private _opened: boolean = false;

  private _toggleSidebar() {
    this._opened = !this._opened;
  }
```

The problem is, button doesn't reflect on screen at all and in addition, none happens. Please help sort this out.

Comment: Provide your `app.module.ts`. Have you imported `SidebarModule` there?

Comment: Yes i have done it all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change your HTML to something like:

```
<div class="page-header custom-phead">
  <ng-sidebar-container>
    <ng-sidebar [(opened)]="_opened">
      <p>Sidebar contents</p>
    </ng-sidebar>
    <!-- you can also try to add a div below if your content not visible -->
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
  </ng-sidebar-container>

  <button (click)="_toggleSidebar()">Toggle</button>

  <form class="heading">
    <input type="text" name="search" [(ngModel)]="search">
    <input type="image" [src]="'../resource/searchicon.png'">
  </form>
</div>
```

please note, that I took `<button (click)="_toggleSidebar()">Toggle</button>` out of `ng-sidebar-container`. If you sidebar content still does not get visible, try to add `<div style="clear:both;"></div>` just before closing `ng-sidebar-container` tag.

I created a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/eP3gOdP4k0ST8rtIWafq?p=preview) which uses both methods for toggling sidebar: `[(opened)]="_opened"` and `close()` and `open()` functions. It may help you with your project

Comment: I even tried with .close() and .open() initially.The problem  is, i see no activity happening on click.The content of ng-sidebar is never revealed.  But in .ts, function gets triggered returning true and false on click of button.

Comment: Could you please share the plunker so i can verify if i missed any?

Comment: Sorry, completely forgot to share plunker link: https://plnkr.co/edit/eP3gOdP4k0ST8rtIWafq?p=preview, I updatet my original answer as well (added plunker link)

Comment: as an alternative, you can also consider using material design sidebar - https://material.angular.io/components/sidenav/overview

Comment: Sidebar isn't responsive at all

Comment: Am sorry..it is more of styling issue.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning height:100vh ..that solved issue and now am able to view the sidebar well...Gotta check for a way to close it on click outside.

Comment: Thanks a lot Andriy.

Answer (score 2):

Andriy solution was not working for Angular6 so adding my answer here.

As mention in the [ReadME.md](https://github.com/arkon/ng-sidebar#usage) of official doc you need to mention the height element for the sidebar-container.

Given code works for me

app.component.html

```
<div>
    <ng-sidebar-container style=" height: 100vh">
    <ng-sidebar [(opened)]="_opened" mode="push" autoCollapseWidth=100>

      <p>Sidebar contents</p>
      <p>Sidebar contents</p>
      <p>Sidebar contents</p>
      <p>Sidebar contents</p>
      <p>Sidebar contents</p>

    </ng-sidebar>

    <!-- Page content -->
    <div ng-sidebar-content>
      <button (click)="_toggleSidebar()">Toggle sidebar</button>
    </div>

  </ng-sidebar-container>    
</div>
```

app.component.ts

```
public _opened: boolean = false;

public _toggleSidebar() {
this._opened = !this._opened;
}
```

in app.module.ts import sideBar as

```
imports: [
    SidebarModule.forRoot()
]
```

Comment: beautiful answer, It helped me resolve my issue. Thank you!